# Markup ommited by Google Code Prettify

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-code-prettify

In my view I have following piece of code:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums lang-cs">
    @Model.ArticleText
</pre>
```

If ArticleText is just a text containing code syntax, for example:

```
"public ArticlesViewModel()
{
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }
}"
```

Then, in the view, this text is displayed as a pretty syntax-highlighted piece of code. But what if I want to add some comment to that text, for example:

```
"This is articles ViewModel:
public ArticlesViewModel()
{
    public string ArticleName { get; set; }
}"
```

Is there any markup I can wrap that comment with, that will be ignored by Code-Prettify?

Answer (score 1):

From the code:

```
/**
* A class that indicates a section of markup that is not code, e.g. to allow
* embedding of line numbers within code listings.
* @const
*/
var PR_NOCODE = 'nocode'
```